# Loop through class html and pass a json property

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, json, ajax

I am building a simple application, where I am doing a Ajax request to get a Json object, and pass it to html, basically a vending machine where I need to pass the product quantity in this case.

basically my problem is, I have a html where I have like 8 divs, and in each div I have a p class with the product quantity, in the other side in the javascript, I am doing a ajax request to get a json object, and in this object I have 8 propertys that are the 8 quantity of each p tag.

**here is my Ajax request to get the json**

```
$.ajax({
        url: " https://api.thingspeak.com/channels/xxxxxx/feeds",
        dataType: 'json',
        data: {
            api_key: apiKeyLeitura,
        },           
        success: function(data){
            var fields = data.feeds[0]; // todos os campos do objecto 
            delete fields.created_at; // eliminar propriedas desnecessárias como a data, é apenas importante neste momento a quantidade de produtos
            delete fields.entry_id; // elimina propriedade desnecessária
               //IMPORTANT THIS LOOP
                for(var f in fields){
                    console.log(fields[f]);
                }
        },
        error: function(xhr,error){
            console.log(xhr);
            console.log(error);
        }
    });
```

what I need to know is, how can I pass the fields[f] data to my class html directly, where each field[i] should correspond to each html[i] what I mean is, each field that I get from the json success, should correspond directly to the html class loop, how can I solve that?

**here is a bit of what my html is**

```
 <div class="col-md-3 SeccaoProduto">
    <p>Coca Cola</p>
    <p>Quantidade Atual:</p>
    <p id="quantidadeCola" class="quantidadeProduto"></p>
 </div>
 <div class="col-md-3 SeccaoProduto">
     <p>Ice Tea</p>
     <p>Quantidade Atual:</p>
     <p id="quantidadeIceTea" class="quantidadeProduto"></p>
 </div>
```

I want to pass the data to that last p in each col-md-3

**I got this code atm**

```
 $(".quantidadeProduto").each(function(key,value){
                $(this).html(fields[key]);
                console.log(fields[key]);
            });
```

I can match each class with a value, but that fields more properly the key, is there a way I can get the property based on the key ?

Comment: What does the data you are returning look like? Does it have a key to distinguish between quantidadeCola and quantitdadeIceTea, is it a key value pair structure?

Comment: forget the id, just focus on the class, i need to iterate over every 1 and place the value of every atribute from json, i dont have a value pair structure :/

Comment: You cannot "forget" about the id, you need someway to join the product and it's quantity to an element they need to share a commonality such as data item key = element id. Show an example of the data you are looping over.

Answer (score 0):

You must use templating engine like Marko, Jade or EJS

Comment: can not use those templating engines :/

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can give a special id to every of your p tags for quainity. For example, in the first div you will have tag p with id="quantity1", second div with tag p with id="quantity2"...
And then, when you iterate thru your JSON, you just find the p tag which id is "quantity"+your iterator

Answer (score 0):

You can make your HTML IDs match your data keys and then just do a simple insert.

Add an ID to your coca-cola quantity p `<p id="coca-cola">`

This is some presumed code for your ajax loop:

```
for (var f in data){

    document.getElementById(f).textContent = 'Quantidade Atual:' + data[f]

}
```

You can even take that one step further and dynamically append your `<p>` inside your ajax call

Answer (score 0):

It is hard to know without seeing an exmaple of the data you are iterating over. I'm assuming you are utilizing Jquery since you are making a call to `$.ajax()`. If you define your data structure, returned from your service, as an object which holds the key name and the value you can use Jquery to then find the element with that id and set the text  of that element i.e.

data:  `[{key:'quantidadeCola', qty:5}, {key:'quantidadeIceTea', qty: 10}]`

This will allow you to use Jquery in the loop as follows:

```
for(var f in fields){
    $('#'+f.key).text(f.qty);
}
```

That being said you should look into model binding frameworks that already keep the html DOM and the javascript object model consistent. There are many frameworks you can choose from: AngularJS, Angular 2, Ember, Backbone, Knockout etc.